# How to search for a string within multiple workbooks using Openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am wanting to search through a directory of workbooks for certain words within cells and get Python to return the workbook names that contain those words. So far I have been able to loop through each workbook, print each workbook name and the sheet names using the code below, but I don't know the right syntax to loop through each cell and search for a string.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"T:\DHFCS SSC\17.0 ILS\Jacob WIP\Cable schedules\Cable schedules"
sheets = os.listdir(path)
sheets = [_ for _ in sheets if not _.startswith('~')]

for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet)
    wb2 = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, sheet))
    print(wb2.get_sheet_names())
    ##wb2._archive.close()
```

What do I need to add to this to search for a word in all of the spreadheets and print the spreadsheet names that contain it?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested I have worked out how to do this. The file will prompt a user for a directory of the Excel files and then ask for a search term, then return the names of the spreadsheets containing that term.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = input("Paste the directory to search (right click on icon in top left > edit > paste: ")
string = input("Enter the search term in lower case: ")
print('Searching...')
workbooks = os.listdir(path)
workbooks = [_ for _ in workbooks if not _.startswith('~')]

for workbook in workbooks:
    wb2 = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, workbook))
    for sheet_name in (wb2.get_sheet_names()):
        sheet = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        for value in sheet.values:
            if string in " ".join([str(_).lower() for _ in value if _ ]):
                print(workbook)
```